# How do I make sure that a block of code only executes ONCE and only ONCE. And NEVER AGAIN

Tags: java

I've tried creating a public static variable (NOT LOCAL) and purposely making an increment to it and telling Java:

"If this variable == 0, then execute this code"

so that even if that method is called the second time, that block of code won't execute because the variable has changed and is no longer zero... and it will never again be zero because it keeps increasing.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  if(e.getSource()==deal){/*do something*/}
}
```

My problem is that the if statment executes more than once when I press the button "deal".

Comment: Well if it keeps increasing it can overflow and come back to 0 at a certain point. So it won't prevent your block of code from executing multiple times. You can use a boolean field, it would suit more to your problem.

Comment: You can also use a static initializer, but you should give us the code and your exact intention

Comment: Other than 0 and non zero, can you make it boolean true/false? If strictly it has to be executed only once, take care of concurrency.

Comment: @Dici, static initializers can execute more than once if there are multiple classloaders, so that's not exactly the universal solution. As this question is worded, the OP better place the code at the start of the `main()` function and also post an armed guard near the user to prevent him from launching the same application ever again.

Comment: I would add a picture but i can't, still don't have enough reputation. It's an if statement that's in the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) Method. and it's basically saying if the button is clicked then do something. and yes it does do it...its just that it does it more than once. and there's is no where in my code where i tell it to do so. When this button is clicked there's a JOptionPane that pops up...and i want this to happen once. YES i have tried using boolean values, still the same. It's just like changing a value from 0 to 1.

Comment: Are you sure, your static variable is global?

Comment: It might be nitpicking, but then again you asked: static variables live inside the class loader. If you have multiple class loaders the code will run for each of them.

Comment: You need to synchronize to make sure the code is not entered two times in parallel.

Comment: @eckes, now that we know he's doing it in EDT, synchronization issues are no longer a problem.

Comment: @Ndum'ndayiMhlongo, could you show us the code that doesn't work? No need for pictures, just the code.

Comment: You dont show code, I bet it is a trivial problem like missing `{` braces or similar. With Gui it might be harder to test it with an debugger, but you can always add println() to follow the code flow. Unless you show a reproducer we cant help you.

Comment: You can add the image URL, someone will inline it for you (but showing code is better done in text!).

Comment: question edited. code added

Comment: @Ndum'ndayiMhlongo, and where's your `boolean` you said didn't work?

Comment: yeap. didn't work. I have another idea. This button is supposed to pop up MessageDialog, "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog". is there a way to CHANGE what the OK button does when you click it ?

Comment: Why not just persist the flag?  If you set a variable to false in a database or flat file, each time it runs to check against the value, it will not execute.   You can cache the value too if performance is a problem.

Comment: EVERYONE i have fixed my problem. THANK YOU for your effort and kindness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
public class Test {
    private boolean isExecuted;
    public synchronized void executeOnce() { 
        if (isExecuted) {
            return;
        } else {
            //do your stuff
            isExecuted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Modify it as per your requirement. To improve performance, you can use double checked locking.

Comment: If it's synchronized anyway, then `volatile` isn't needed. Using DCL, it would be needed, though. Or just use an `AtomicBoolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, It's dummy code but through this way, you can execute `inner for loop` code only once.

```
List<WebElement> allelements = driver.findElements(By.id("id1"));   

int i = 0;

for (WebElement e : allelements) 
{
    i++;

    List<WebElement> secondelements = driver.findElements(By.id("id2"));
    if(i==1)
    {
        for(WebElement ae : secondelements)
        {
                System.out.println(ae.getText());   
        }
    }
    System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```